# Struggling with specific Vlook up - Or do I even need Vlookup?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

Righto,

I need a formula to put in A2. I need to compare B2:B10 to G2:G10, and if theres a match, return the value in F.

[image]

For example, if the formula was in A1, it'd find the matching number (4321) in G7, and then return the value in F7 back to A1

I've tried using Index with Match, but didn't work :( Any suggestions?

Comment: What if there is more than one match ???

Comment: The Values in Column G might have duplicates, but F should be unique - If theres any duplicates in my example, that's my bad! hehe

Answer (score 0):

An index and match should solve this.  Index the range you want to return, and then an exact match looking up your value in column B to the range in column G should get you the value you are looking for.

Example if typed into cell A2 in your picture:

=INDEX($F$2:$F$10, MATCH($B2, $G$2:$G$10,0) )

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one match for each value in column G, I would use the following Index/Match formula in field A2:

```
=index(F:F, match(B2,G:G,0))
```

Note: I will only return the first value if the value appears multiple times in the column.

Answer (score 0):

In **H2** enter:

```
=IF(B2=G2,F2,"")
```

and copy down.  In **A2** enter:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,H2:H10)
```

This will gather all matches.

[image]